# PHP Curl not accepting variables

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to pass some arguments in Curl but I realize that when I use test data (simple strings), I can get the result (payId and payUrl) but when I use variables instead of test data, I get nothing back.

What's the best way to troubleshoot this type of issue? It's my first time using Curl so I'm creating this function based on articles I found here.

For instance, if I replace "name" with $clientName, I won't get any return from the API.

```
function generatePayment($sendId, $clientCPF, $clientName, $clientEmail, $clientCep, $clientPhone, $amount){
    
    
    // CONFIG
    $urlCallBack = "http://192.168.0.79/sistema/admin/shipList.php?transactionStatus=success";
    $urlError = "http://192.168.0.79/sistema/admin/shipList.php?transactionStatus=failed";
    $debug = true;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'urlhere');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n\t\"reference\": \"my-order-ref-0001\",\n\t\"client\": {\n    \t\"cpf\": \"43164853858\",\n    \t\"name\": \"John Doe\",\n    \t\"email\": \"johndoe@example.com\",\n    \t\"birthdate\": \"1982-01-14\",\n    \t\"cep\": \"18053190\",\n    \t\"phone\": \"15987452584\"\n\t},\n\t\"items\": [\n    \t{\n        \t\"reference\": \"my-item-ref-0001\",\n        \t\"description\": \"Apple iMac 21.5-inch\",\n        \t\"quantity\": \"1\",\n        \t\"amount\": 149900\n    \t},\n    \t{\n        \t\"reference\": \"my-item-ref-0002\",\n        \t\"description\": \"Apple iPhone 11 Pro\",\n        \t\"quantity\": 1,\n        \t\"amount\": 99900\n    \t}\n\t],\n     \"coupon\": {\n         \"code\": \"10DESCONTO\",\n         \"value\": 1000,\n         \"issuer\": \"merchant_api\"\n     },\n\t\"shipping\": {\n           \"amount\": 1000\n\t},\n\t\"redirect\": {\n    \t      \"success\": \"https://example.com/sp_callback?success\",\n    \t      \"failed\": \"https://example.com/sp_callback?failed\"\n\t}\n}");
    
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$_POST['token'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        if ($debug){
            echo "<BR><BR><BR> DATA PASSED TO FUNCTION <BR>";
            echo "<br>sendId ===> ".$sendId;
            echo "<br>clientCPF ===> ".$clientCPF;
            echo "<br>clientName ===> ".$clientName;
            echo "<br>clientEmail ===> ".$clientEmail;
            echo "<br>clientCep ===> ".$clientCep;
            echo "<br>clientPhone ===> ".$clientPhone;
            echo "<br>amount ===> ".$amount;
            
            $decode = json_decode($result,true);
            
            echo "<BR><BR> DATA RECEIVED FROM API <BR>";
            echo '<br> payId generated by API ==> '.$payId = $decode['data']['order_id'];
            echo '<br> PayURL generated by API ==>'.$payUrl = $decode['data']['url_checkout'];

        } else {
            $decode = json_decode($result,true);
            $transactionId = $decode['data']['order_id'];
            $payUrl = $decode['data']['url_checkout'];
            $_SESSION['transactionUrl'] = $decode['data']['url_checkout'];
            $_SESSION['transactionId'] = $transactionId;
            $_SESSION['sendId'] = $sendId;
        }
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    // END GENERATE PAYMENT
}
```

Any help is appreciated on how to troubleshoot.

---

**Updating Code using JSON**

---

```
//INITIALIZE
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sandbox.splipay.com/api/orders');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    
    // POST
 
    $post = array(
            "items" => array (
                "description" => "Test",
                "quantity" => 1,
                "amount" => 10
            ),
            "redirect" => array (
                "success" => "www.success",
                "failed" => "www.success"
            )
        );
    
    $post = json_encode($post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    
    // HEADERS
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$_POST['token'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
    //EXECUTE
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        $arr = json_decode($result);
        echo "<br><br>Return from VAR_DUMP";
        var_dump ($arr);
        echo "<BR><BR>INFO RETURN<BR>";
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        var_dump ($info);
        
        // $_POST['token'] = $arr['access_token'];
        
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

As per documentation, these are the only values I need to pass to the API and I'd get the following response (example):

{
"success": true,
"data": {
"order_id": 57,
"url_checkout": "https://sandbox.splipay.com/payment/4openRe7Az/kzPdyP7bQr?expires=1583164527&signature=e1caae419137903f930f5a5b3d4c72608a61c0fdd36c70803d4a92c15556a4c5"
}
}

Comment: Don't create JSON by substituting into a string. Put everything in an array and use `json_encode()`.

Comment: You should be replacing `John Doe` with `$clientName`, not replacing `name`.

Comment: Just ran the curl_getinfo and realized that I get HTTP code 302 when I switch from string to the variable.

Comment: By the way @barmar, that's exactly what I'm trying. Replacing John Doe with the $clientName.

Comment: @barmar I replace with JSON encode and sending only the mandatory data as per documentation I have. Getting Null when decoding json. Is this the right Json formatting/encoding?

$post = array(
            "items" => array (
                "description" => "Test",
                "quantity" => 1,
                "amount" => 10,
            ),
            "redirect" => array (
                "success" => "www.success",
                "failed" => "www.success",
            )
        );
    
    $post = json_encode($post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

Comment: Please add the code that is not working so we can debug that code not the working code with us guessing what changes your making.

Comment: @barkermn01 I've update the code. Now I'm trying to trigger using JSON format and only with the mandatory fields. I'm getting an empty array still.

Comment: `302` is a redirect. Enable the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option to follow the redirect automatically.

Answer (score 0):

After moving to a JSON format and reviewing the API requirements, I was able to fix this. Once in JSON, it was easier to identify that there was issue with the multi dimensional array. I rewrote the code and it's working now. Thanks everyone

JSON

```
$post = array(
            "reference" => "my-order-ref-0001",
            "client" => array (
                "cpf" => "43164853858",
                "name" => "John Doe",
                "email" => "johndoe@example.com",
                "birthdate" => "1982-01-14",
                "cep" => "18053190",
                "phone" => "15987452584"
            ),
            "items" => array (
                array (
                    "reference" => "my-item-ref-0001",
                    "description" => "Test",
                    "quantity" => 1,
                    "amount" => 10
                ),
            ),
            "coupon" => array(
                "code" => "10DESCONTO",
                "value" => 1000,
                "issuer" => "merchant_api"
            ),
            "shipping" => array (
                "amount"=> 1000
            ),
            "redirect" => array (
                "success" => "www.success",
                "failed" => "www.success"
            )
        );
```